# What should be done to create a full iOS app in tamil language?

Tags: ios, tamil, localized

I want to create an iOS application which consists of Tamil language. I see so many applications in appstore which is fully of tamil language. But, it is not a localized language in iPhone. So how can we achieve it? How are they developing a complete tamil application in iPhone? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. Simply enter any text in your .xib (or programmatically) in Tamil using a font that has the Tamil characters, and it will be displayed in Tamil on all systems, regardless of their language setting. (In other words, it will not be localized to any other language.)

Comment: I saw in some sites that we have to localize by creating localized.strings and create a project for a local language with ISO standard like ta.lproj.. Is that really necessary? Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: You have to use ta.lproj if you want to support many languages.If only tamil-just write it all up without any .lproj